# How to use try catch block in Page.RegisterAsyncTask methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous

I have the following code to run some asynchronous call. I am trying to capture the database timeout exception and show some user friendly message.

But putting `try, catch block in endInvoke, action` does not getting executed. I am using ASP.Net 4.0 & C# 4.0

```
Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(new BeginEventHandler(beginMyMethod)
      , new EndEventHandler(endMyMethod), new EndEventHandler(timeout => { })
      , true, true));
Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();
```

Then

```
IAsyncResult beginMyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object state)
{
        Action r = myMethod;
        return r.BeginInvoke(cb, state);
}


void endMyMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
  try{
   myObj.Property // gives object reference error, as it was not set, since DB timeout

  }
  catch(MyTimeoutException ex){
   //it is not getting called
  }
}


private void MyMethod()
{
 try{
   MyObject myObj= //making a database call causes DB time out error
 }
 catch(MyTimeoutException ex){
    //it is getting called
 }
}
```

**How to use try catch block in Page.RegisterAsyncTask methods**

Note: ***I want to prevent object reference error with db time out and async operation***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that `myObj.Property` results in a `NullReferenceException`. Why do you expect to catch it with a `catch (MyTimeoutException)`, then?

You are using the APM pattern. This requires calling the `EndXxx` method to get the result of the operation, get any exceptions and potentially release resources. Call the `EndXxx` method.

Comment: You are right. I am able to catch the exception in original method. But however i need to check the null value before accessing in `endXXX`.

Comment: So why don't you do it?

Comment: why don't you try catching mutiple times (both **catch( MyTimeOutException)** and **catch (NullReferenceException)** ?

Comment: Don't catch NRE. `if (myObj == null) return;`.